# C# Parsing a string with regex or regular iteration

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have a string which can be in any of the following formats and I am expecting outputs as such:-

```
if E31f -> E
if E3X -> E3
if E3 -> E3
if M5 -> M
if BR30O -> BR
if BR10E -> BR
if BRC -> BR
if BR3 -> BR3
if BR3R -> BR3
if WT2O -> WT
if WT3E -> WT3
if T1A -> T
if T3O -> T3
if TO2 -> TO
if TO3E -> TO3
if EL6 -> EL
if EL3 -> EL3
if E -> E
if T3 -> T3
if BC1 -> BC
if BC3 -> BC3
```

I would like to find out if the input string is `E3E/E3F/E3O`, then the output should be -> `'E3'` only.

Otherwise, if the input string is `E31F`, then the output should be -> `'E'` only.

The beginning letter 'E' is just a sample... it can be BR3, WT3, T3, TO3, EL3, BC3. It may or may NOT contain the number '3'.

I am trying to find out if, after the first few characters when the numerical value exists... does the number 3 exist by itself, if yes then extract the characters and the number 3 (E3, BR3, etc etc).

However if after the first few characters, the number 3 exists appended by other numbers, then only extract the characters leading upto the numbers in the string (E, BR, etc etc).

I am trying to figure out what is the best way of doing this. Is it with regex or should I used the regular way of using a for loop to iterate through the string.

Comment: Please provide some sample input / expected output strings. You didn't list any "formats", and it's not clear what you're looking for (at least to me).

Comment: I did. Sample inputs were - E31E. E34F. E3E....

Comment: not sure what you mean by copied and pasted. If an input string is E34F, my output should be E... however if it is E3F then my output should be E

Comment: I think the slashes and spaces threw me - you have them all on the same line, without any quotes. Also, when you say "format" you mean the string is literally one of those four strings? With no other content?

Comment: Philo, please read about [mcve].

Comment: You need to explain this better. Those aren't 'formats', you've given 1 string with 6 'words' (`--`, `E31E`, etc). If I look at what you have there, you don't need regex or anything, an if and a contains would do it

Comment: I am lost is this a question? or exercise?

Comment: It's better to explain, what you have and then what you wanted to. So, let us see what you tried to get your desired output.

Comment: OK you haven't explained your condition to pick properly. Based on what do you want to pick either `E3` or `E` only?

Comment: You say *"The beginning letter 'E' is just a sample... it can be BR3, WT3, T3, TO3, EL3, BC3"* but now it's even more unclear what output you want if it begins with (or equals?) one of these. Please try to explain what the "format" is (i.e. which parts should be ignored, which parts are relevant) and then provide a list of *actual* sample strings and the expected output strings. By copy/paste I mean I can copy your code and paste it into a `Main` method in visual studio.

Comment: trying my best to explain. english is not my first lang

Comment: No problem. Code is a common language here, it speaks the clearest.

Comment: OK, this is better. What if there is no `3` in the string?

Comment: if there is no 3...that is okay... Say EL43XC -> EL.... or say just EL -> EL

Answer (score 1):

Here's an edited version of the answer after OP edited the question.

### Regex

> .+  ==>  Take 1 or more characters.
>
> 3 ==> 3 must be present.
>
> [A-Za-z0-9] ==> Get the character/number immediately after the 3.
>
> .* ==> Zero or more characters to end the string.

```
var regex = new Regex(@"(.+)3([A-Za-z0-9]).*");
```

Here, `Groups[2]` contains the value that comes immediately after `3`. `Groups[1]` contains the characters leading up to `3`.

So, by using `int.TryParse()`, if the value immediately after `3` is a number, we only get the characters leading up to `3`. Else (i.e., the character after `3` is not a number), then we get the preceding characters + 2.

```
var list = new List<string>() { "E31F", "E3X", "BR39FG", "BR3X" };

foreach (var word in list)
{
    var match = regex.Match(word);
    if (match.Success)
    {
        var after3 = match.Groups[2].Value;
        string result = string.Empty;
        if (int.TryParse(after3, out int res))
        {
            result = match.Groups[1].Value;
        }
        else
        {
            result = match.Groups[1].Value + "3";
        }
        Console.WriteLine("{0} ==> {1}", word, result);
    }
}
```

### Output

> E31F ==> E
>
> E3X ==> E3
>
> BR39FG ==> BR
>
> BR3X ==> BR3

### EDIT2 (after OP posted clarification)

So the updated conditions:

> E, M, BR, WT, T, TO, EL, BC are primary strings I am looking for. And
>   then I am looking to see if it is followed by the number 3 only. If
>   yes, then I want the character prefix and number appended. If not,
>   then only the character prefix.

I would, in this case, abandon the `Regex` approach. Here's a code with explanations.

```
static void Main()
{
    var words = new List<string>() { "E31f", "E3X", "E3", "M5", "BR30O", "BR10E", "BRC", "BR3", "BR3R", "WT2O", "WT3E", "T1A", "T3O", "TO2", "TO3E", "EL6", "EL3", "E", "T3", "BC1", "BC3" };
    var keywords = new List<string>() { "E", "M", "BR", "WT", "T", "TO", "EL", "BC" };

    // We need to be a little tactful here. Your keyword list contains both E and EL, so if we simply do a `string.Contains()`, we want to make sure that EL is considered before E.
    // So we sort by length first, and then by ascending order.
    // So the sorted keywords look like this: BC,BR,EL,TO,WT,E,M,T
    var sortedKeywords = keywords.OrderByDescending(x => x.Length).ThenBy(x => x);

    foreach (var word in words)
    {
        var extract = string.Empty;

        // We see if the selected word in the list starts with any of the keys in the sorted list.
        // Since we started it, EL will be checked before E, TO will be checked before T, etc.
        var key = sortedKeywords.FirstOrDefault(word.StartsWith);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(key))
        {
            extract = key;
            // We set the extract = key. Now if key is the same as the word, we simply contiue the loop.
            if (word.Length > key.Length)
            {
                // If there are more characters we check the next character.
                var next = word.Skip(key.Length).Take(1).FirstOrDefault().ToString();
                if (int.TryParse(next, out int num))
                {
                    if (num == 3)
                    {
                        // If the next character is 3 and there are more characters
                        if (word.Length > key.Length + 1)
                        {
                            // Check the next of next
                            var nextnext = word.Skip(key.Length + 1).Take(1).FirstOrDefault().ToString();
                            // If next of next is not a number, we append 3 to the ky
                            // Otherwise extract is the same as the key which we already set
                            if (!int.TryParse(nextnext, out num))
                            {
                                extract = key + 3.ToString();
                            }
                        }
                        // If the next character is 3 and its the last one, we append 3 to the key
                        else
                        {
                            extract = key + 3.ToString();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("{0} --> \t{1}", word, extract);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

### Output

> E31f     --> E
>
> E3X      --> E3
>
> E3       --> E3
>
> M5       --> M
>
> BR30O    --> BR
>
> BR10E    --> BR
>
> BRC      --> BR
>
> BR3      --> BR3
>
> BR3R     --> BR3
>
> WT2O     --> WT
>
> WT3E     --> WT3
>
> T1A      --> T
>
> T3O      --> T3
>
> TO2      --> TO
>
> TO3E     --> TO3
>
> EL6      --> EL
>
> EL3      --> EL3
>
> E        --> E
>
> T3       --> T3
>
> BC1      --> BC
>
> BC3      --> BC3

Comment: This is good. but it fails for E3.
Expected results :-
E3 -> E3

Comment: It will also fail for examples like:-

BRC => BR, 
BR10E => BR

Comment: so there might not always be numbers/characters after the number 3. Also, the number 3 might not always be present.

Comment: That's because you didn't define your conditions properly. You didn't say earlier that there would be cases where 3 is the last character.

Comment: It's impossible to provide a solution without a properly defined set of conditions. According to your new updated post it's even more unclear, for example, for BRC you say you must extract BR. So what's the deciding factor there to extract those.

Comment: E, M, BR, WT, T, TO, EL, BC are primary strings I am looking for. And then I am looking to see if it is followed by the number 3 only. If yes, then I want the character prefix and number appended. If not, then only the character prefix.

Comment: I have been working on the regex this morning and I have a blue print:- (its not correct)

new Regex(@"([A-Z]{0,2}) +[0-9]{0,2} ([A-Za-z0-9]).*");

part 1, extract the first character or first two characters (if exists). 
part 2, extract if number exists after that... if number exists, then check if number is 3 only, if yes -> output = part1 + 3, if no, then output -> part1

Comment: @Philo updated the answer.